# Read multiple files into separate data frames and process every dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

for all the files in one directory, I want to read each file into a data frame then process the file, for example, calculate cor across columns. For example:

```
files<-list.files(path=".") <br>
names <- substr(files,18,20)

for(i in c(1:length(names))){
     name <- names[i]    
     assign (name, read.table(files[i]))
     sapply(3:ncol(name), function(y) cor(name[, 2], name[, y], ))      
}
```

but 'name' is a string in the last statement of the code, how can I process the dataframe 'name'?

Comment: Store all the `data.frames` in a list. ie `dat <- lapply(files, read.table)` then you can `lapply` over the list again to process them  (or just add that into a function defined in the first `lapply`.

Comment: If either of the answers helped you remember to check one

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what R's lists are for. Also calling `sapply` to get all of the correlations is unnecessary since `cor` returns the correlation matrix so you can just subset

```
R> files <- list.files(pattern = "tsv")
R> dat <- lapply(files, read.table)
R> dat
[[1]]
          a        b  c
1  2.802164 4.835557  6
2  1.680186 4.974198  3
3  3.002777 4.670041  6
4  2.182691 5.137982 11
5  4.206979 5.170269  5
6  1.307195 4.753041  9
7  2.919497 4.657171  7
8  2.938614 5.305558  9
9  2.575200 4.893604  2
10 1.548161 4.871108  4

[[2]]
            a b  c
1  -1.8483890 2  6
2  -2.9035164 0  7
3  -0.6490283 1  6
4  -2.8842633 3  2
5  -1.8803775 0 12
6  -3.0267870 1  9
7   0.5287124 0  7
8  -3.7220733 0  2
9  -2.0663912 2  9
10 -1.6232248 1  6
```

You can then `lapply` over this `list` again to process or do it as a one liner.

```
R> dat <- lapply(files, function(x) cor(read.table(x))[1,-1] )
R> dat
[[1]]
          b           c 
 0.27236143 -0.04973541 

[[2]]
         b          c 
-0.1440812  0.2771511
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to put all the files you wish to read in in one folder, and then work with lists:

```
your.dir <- ""  # adjust
files <- list.files(your.dir)

your.dfs <- lapply(file.path(your.dir, files), read.table)
```

`your.dfs`is now a list holding all your data frames. You can perform functions on all data frames simultaneously using lapply, or you can access individual data frames with the usual subsetting syntax, for example `your.dfs[[1]]` to access the first data frame.